# Java swt text autocomple

Tags: java, autocomplete, swt

I am trying to create an autocomplete feature for a swt text field. However i cant find a working example for IContentProposalProvider etc. The eclipse autosuggest feature when writing is close to what i am trying to achieve. Please dont suggest using external libraries. Thanks!

Comment: I can find several results when typing your title into google...

Comment: .. Checked them and non of them works the way i want

Comment: Can you be more precise? How does their functionality differ from what you want?

Comment: I want the autocomplete to be like the one in eclipse. + there arent any good examples out there

Comment: Have you had a look at the Eclipse source code? It's open source...